# GCloud reset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts

I have a GCloud credentials which are frequently rotated and a bash script which uses them.
I want to detect in the bast script if during the run, the credentials are changed and to overwrite them.

My logic is:

1. Fetch the the SA json and use export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="${current_sa_path}"
2. watch for rotations in the SA
3. If rotation happens I try to modify the `current_sa_path` with the new json value

So I have something like this:

```
function check_for_new_sa() {
    new_sa_path=<get-path-to-the-new-sa-json>

    diff "${current_sa_path}" "${new_sa_path}"
    if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
      cat ${new_sa_path} > "${current_sa_path}"
      unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
      export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="${current_sa_path}"
    fi
    rm -rf ${new_sa_path}
}
```

Unfortunately I see that gcloud did not notice this change and was still trying to connect via the old service-account. Maybe once it is exported, it is cached somewhere or idk. Do you have any ideas how can I reset it?

You also can easily reproduce it by exporting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to one file.
After that modify this file and when you try some command, gcloud will use the old file credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write "`gcloud`", I assume you mean some client application; `gcloud` itself does not use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable.

Because you `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` before running your application, the application will hold the credentials in memory. If the credentials change, you've >2 solutions:

1. Terminate the app process and restart it so that it reads the updated `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable value
2. Update your app (!) to look for changes in the file that that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` references and restart it when the file changes.

I think option #1 is preferable because, when running on GCP, Application Credentials will be obtained from the Metadata service rather than a file.

Comment: Add these commands to your answer: **gcloud auth revoke** and **gcloud auth activate-service-account**. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: Thanks @john-hanley. Because the OP uses `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, I think they're not trying to authenticate `gcloud` but an app. But, we'll see!

Comment: You are correct. Most applications that use ADC, only load the credentials in the class constructor once. Also, their script is not even changing the path.